# gdi+ - Graphics.MeasureString either too wide or too narrow

Tags: c#, gdi+, system.drawing, drawstring

I'm using the `System.Drawing` library in C# to measure a string's size:

```
SizeF size = gfx.MeasureString("Hello", myFont);
```

However, this returns a size with a bit of spacing around the text. Here's the text rendered with a red bounding box that represents the size `MeasureString` returned. The TopLeft corner of both the box and the text is exactly the same point.

[image: Hello with a spacious bounding box]

I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798336/graphics-measurestring-allowing-too-much-whitespace) on Stack Overflow that recommended using `StringFormat.GenericTypographic` to remove the spacing. So I changed my code to the following:

```
SizeF size = gfx.MeasureString("Hello", myFont, 0, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
```

Which yields the following result (again, the TopLeft corner of the box and the text is identical):

[image: Hello without spacing but the bounding box cuts into the text]

Almost perfect, but the size is consistently too narrow and cuts into the last letter. These results are reproducible with any font of any size I tried, with any string and with any `width` parameter.

My current workaround is to offset the text 5 pixels to the left when drawing it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I also had to **draw** the string using `StringFormat.GenericTypographic`, not just measure with it. The new DrawString call looks like this:

```
gfx.DrawString("Hello", myFont, myBrush, topLeft, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
```

Comment: Hum, `MeasureString` is supposed to give the same results as `DrawString`